# Can't connect noise texture node in "Shading"

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I was trying to add noise texture node in shading according to YouTube lessons, but instead of multi-colored noise texture I get pink appearance (as it was before texture creation). Why I get such a result and what can I do? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Lesson is [here](https://youtu.be/Rh5gAQLtOls), event is near to 2:30.

Blend file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JUmpRtEIjX5ztosEqUc93hsf1wI7hmiS/view?usp=sharing).

[image: Situation]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: @Chris Yes, of course. 1 minute...

Comment: @Chris Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

you showed in your screenshot another setup than in your blend file.

So you see the rose color whenever something is "missing".

[image]

So in your blend file, it seems like your image texture "Dough texture" is missing (maybe misspelled or moved to another folder).

You cannot see the noise texture, because you plugged it in "displacement".
(you can see that too, but not as color, but as yeah...displacement)
If you wanna see it as color, plug the noise color output in your surface material output like this:

[image]

if you push the scale value up you will recognize it even more:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Image texture is not missing, I can edit it in "Texture Paint" and I can see it in folder.

Comment: Connection you suggested doesn't help.
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cvQU_EXddHN0yzA4-YOKc0yZr1NICFlA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it works. please do the changes i told you, then do file->external data -> pack resources. after that, save file, and upload again. Then i will check it.

Comment: I don't understand. Have you seen screenshot?

Comment: yes, i have seen the screenshot. But because you are obviously a beginner - there could be happen a lot of things...so i wanna make sure you didn't do something totally wrong...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aqkkvdD7lktV2Jfb17RRUnXkkbgVFy1O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you. i opened it and saw this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4scWI.jpg so it is working....ok, now i am really confused....i am not sure whether you have a problem with your computer/graphics card

Comment: what blender version r u using? and what computer/graphics card do u have?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I have "onboard" graphics card only. Maybe this is the source of problem... or maybe this happens because we have different versions...

Comment: I use 2.80 version and I'm not sure how to explore my integrated card

Comment: i cannot use and test Blender 2.8 because i have a M1 Macbook... :( sorry

Comment: can u try on a newer Blender version?

Comment: It's okay, thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I will update it

Comment: that's weird. i could run blender 2.8 (intel) on my mac and it did work too...

Comment: sorry that i couldn't help...but i am sure someone can help. But it is for sure not the node setup. It must be something different.